# error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MatPaginator'

Tags: angular, pagination, angular-material

I'm trying to follow the tutorial [here](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-material-data-table/) to set up a paginator for my material table in Angular.

I've getting the error, error TS2304: Cannot find name 'MatPaginator' despite importing MatPaginatorModule:

```
import { MatPaginatorModule } from '@angular/material/paginator';
```

In both my all-matches.component and in app.module.

App.module:

```
import { MaterializeModule } from 'angular2-materialize'
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { masterFirebaseConfig } from './api-keys';
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { YoutubeComponent } from './youtube/youtube.component';
import { routing } from './app.routing';
import { NewMatchComponent } from './new-match/new-match.component';
import { CreateAccountComponent } from './create-account/create-account.component';
import { TestDbComponent } from './test-db/test-db.component';
import { LandingComponent } from './landing/landing.component';
import { MatchDisplayComponent } from './match-display/match-display.component';
import { AuthorizationService } from './authorization.service';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { DatabaseService } from './database.service';
import { TextTransformationService } from './text-transformation.service';
import { ValidationService } from './validation.service';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { ProtectionGuard } from './protection.guard';
import { AllMatchesComponent } from './all-matches/all-matches.component';
import { AnnotationDisplayComponent } from './annotation-display/annotation-display.component';
import { D3Service } from './d3.service';
import { NotfoundComponent } from './notfound/notfound.component';
import { UserStatusReportComponent } from './user-status-report/user-status-report.component';
import { PaymentOrAnnotationDetailsComponent } from './payment-or-annotation-details/payment-or-annotation-details.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatSlideToggleModule } from '@angular/material/slide-toggle';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import { MatOptionModule } from '@angular/material/core';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatSortModule } from '@angular/material';
import { MatDatepickerModule, MatNativeDateModule, MatPaginatorModule } from '@angular/material';
import {MatProgressSpinnerModule} from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';

export const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: masterFirebaseConfig.apiKey,
  authDomain: masterFirebaseConfig.authDomain,
  databaseURL: masterFirebaseConfig.databaseURL,
  storageBucket: masterFirebaseConfig.storageBucket
};

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    YoutubeComponent,
    NewMatchComponent,
    CreateAccountComponent,
    TestDbComponent,
    LandingComponent,
    MatchDisplayComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    AllMatchesComponent,
    AnnotationDisplayComponent,
    NotfoundComponent,
    UserStatusReportComponent,
    PaymentOrAnnotationDetailsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    routing,
    MaterializeModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig),
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatOptionModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatPaginatorModule
  ],
  providers: [AuthorizationService, DatabaseService, ProtectionGuard, D3Service, ValidationService, TextTransformationService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

all-matches.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatPaginatorModule } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { D3Service } from '../d3.service';
import { DatabaseService } from '../database.service';
import { TextTransformationService } from '../text-transformation.service';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { MatTableDataSource, MatSort } from '@angular/material';
import { DataSource } from '@angular/cdk/table';
import {MatProgressSpinnerModule} from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';
import { MatchDataSource } from '../matchDataSource.model';
import { AuthorizationService } from '../authorization.service';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-all-matches',
  templateUrl: './all-matches.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./all-matches.component.scss']
})
export class AllMatchesComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit {
  private dataSource: MatchDataSource;
  private columnsToDisplay = ['rank','weightClass', 'ageClass','athlete1Name', 'athlete2Name', 'gender','tournamentName','location', 'date', 'matchRating', 'videoUrl']; //TODO make this dynamic somehow
  private loading = true;
  user: any = null;
  private ngUnsubscribe: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;

  constructor(private authService: AuthorizationService, private d3Service: D3Service, private dbService: DatabaseService, private textTransformationService: TextTransformationService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.getCurrentUser().takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe).subscribe(user=>{
      this.user = user;
    },err=>{
      console.log(err);
    });
    this.dataSource = new MatchDataSource(this.dbService);
    this.dataSource.loadMatches('test', '', '', 0, 3);
    }

    ngAfterViewInit(){
      this.paginator.page
        .pipe(
          tap(()=> this.loadMatchesPage())
        )
        .subscribe();
    }

    loadMatchesPage(){
      this.dataSource.loadMatches('TODO', '', 'asc', this.paginator.pageIndex, this.paginator.pageSize);
    }

    ngOnDestroy(){
      console.log("onDestroy is called");
      this.ngUnsubscribe.next();
      this.ngUnsubscribe.complete();
    }
}
```

It doesn't seem that this is a common problem.

I'm using
"@angular/cdk": "^5.2.5",
"@angular/common": "5.2.7",
"@angular/material": "^5.2.5",

Would the versioning explain the problem? Open to any suggestions. Many thanks in advance. Willing to supply an example if folks thing it's warranted.

Comment: Why are you importing the `MatPaginatorModule` module in the component? All you need there is `MatPaginator`. As in: `import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material';`

Comment: That did the trick. I wish the tutorial had shown that. Thank you!

Comment: That tutorial does seems to lack some basic information.